# Unknown column 'data' in 'field list' in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am creating one website using codeigniter with session. When i load the welcome page in codeigniter its showing the error like:-

> Error Number: 1054, Unknown column 'data' in 'field list', SELECT
>   data FROM ci_sessions WHERE id =
>   '562a04f4kt6j4n6eehsob3vm3puuc3r5',  Filename:
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/ci_ecom/system/database/DB_driver.php,  Line Number:
>   691.

I call the session library and database library in auto load area corretly. I dont know exactly where i did the mistake I check it in C:/xampp/htdocs/ci_ecom/system/database/DB_driver.php this path area also.. 
In my table I put the column name user_data but here its showing Unknown column 'data' in 'field list'.

this is my table stucture

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
        session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
        ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
        user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
        last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        user_data text NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
        KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
    );
```

This is my ci session

```
    $config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
    $config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
    $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
    $config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
    $config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
    $config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
    $config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
    $config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
    $config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;

    any one can u pls help what is the exact problem...
```

Comment: You're querying the database for a column called 'data' from your ci_sessions table, but that column doesn't exist

Comment: add your query in question

Comment: @dhruv jadia this is defaultly running there is no query.. that is the reason i cant understood where to change it.

Comment: @pacio and @ Dhruv Jadia its working fine now... Thanks for your comments.

Comment: There is user_data column in your table structure not data what version of CI you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'd experience this problem in CodeIgniter 3.X. To resolve it: Update the config.php to look like below.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: another error after adding this
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1146

Table 'posa.ci_session' doesn't exist

SELECT 1 FROM `ci_session` WHERE `id` = '54h4pmn6qrq09i65qcviq3jbmntn2sao'

Filename: F:/0Workout/POSFINAL/30nov/POSAccounts/Data/ci_3.1.11/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Answer (score 6):

A straight forward answer is to create the table in this format,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
`id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
`data` blob NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`));
```

and everything should go fine. It's because the session table structure is modified in the latest versions of codeigniter.

Comment: Just to be clear dont miss the last ); I know we all are humans and sometimes in hurry we make this copy paste mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ci_sessions` `table` does not have a data field, yet, in a query not shown in the question you try to load it or write it.